# I don't understand where the get method of the requests object supported by the requests package for Python gets its code

Tags: python, import, package, mapping

I have just installed the requests package. It works, meaning that I can run the first two instructions from the documentation without error, namely import requests and requests.get.

I don't understand the underlying source. I see a directory in site-packages named requests. It contains the necessary `__init__.py` so the system should accept it as a valid object for an import. However, I would expect to see a `get.py` in the directory to correspond to the get in the script. But no such thing exists. In fact the whole directory is amazingly small. Where is everything?

Comment: *"I would expect to see a `get.py`"* - why? Why would there be one file per method? If you read the content of `__init__.py` you can see it comes from `api.py`: https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/9ed5db8ed28e816b597dafd328b342ec95466afa/requests/__init__.py#L123

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`requests.__init__.py`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py) but specifically line 123:

```py
from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options
```

Then if you go into `requests.api.py` you'll find `get()`, which is the source implementation for that method:

```py
def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
    r"""Sends a GET request.
    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param params: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples or bytes to send
        in the query string for the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """

    kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
```

I'm pretty sure by importing `get()` into `__init__.py` that makes it available/invokable via the `requests` module you initially imported.